# URL Structure, subject/action or English order?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I typically work with programming languages that have a Subject.Action() sort of grammar. So if there is a dog that needs to be walked, its usually Dog.Walk()

In this case I'm referring to what would be the verb in English as the action because I don't want anyone to confuse the use of "verb" with the HTTP use of Get, Post, etc. ASP.NET MVC also refers to what is basically the verb as an Action.

So my question is whether there is a compelling argument to creating URLs that use a natural English ordering like mydog.com/Walk/Dog instead of the more typical ordering based on OOP grammars that are usually Dog.Walk() and in a URL become mydog.com/Dog/Walk. Or in the case of the SO page I'm on which is /questions/ask instead of the more English-like /ask/questions.

The English ordering makes for URLs that I think are more readable to normal people and not just programmers. Of course, readers of non-English languages where the grammar has a different order might expect it to be the other way around anyway.

Just wanted to see what thoughts or experiences we all have on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be overly concerned with the english representation of URLS. Although interesting it really doesn't make a huge impact on users visiting a site. Do you have any specific examples of where OOP grammar is an issue for a site. SEO maybe?

I have been in similar situations and I always use OOP grammar to follow the MVC standard controller/action.

/questions/ask
/questions/answer
/questions/edit